# Custom DataAnnotations-Attribute like UIHint

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, custom-attributes

I want to create a custom DataAnnotations-Attribute for my editor as a clean and reuseable way to load the editor in a model like this:

```
class MyModel {
    [MyEditor(ShowPreview: true)]
    public string Text{ get; set; }
}
```

I found out that a custom attribute can be done by inherit from Attribute:

```
class MyEditorAttribute : Attribute { }
```

The problem is: How can I get information about the field like id or name (in this example **Text**) and how can I return my custom template when the html should get rendered in the view like

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
```

The only way I found out which works is using the UIHint-Attribute.

```
class MyModel {
    [UIHint("MyEditor"), AllowHtml]
    public string Text{ get; set; }
}
```

In this example I can add a view named Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyEditor.cshtml which gets automatically rendered for this attribute. There I can get for example the id of the field with `ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)`

But I want to create a custom attribute because its cleaner, I can specify there some attributes for my editor in a clean way. How can I do this using DataAnnotations? I couldn't find information about this. I also searched for the source of the UIHint-Class to see how it works, but although the .NET framework is open source I can't find the source of those class.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create a custom attribute because its cleaner, I can specify there some attributes for my editor in a clean way.

Yes you can do this.

> How can I do this using DataAnnotations?

DataAnnotations is a namespace, don't confuse a name space with a class like `attribute`.  What you want is an `Attribute`.

First create an attribute that derives from the `UIHintAttribute`.

```
public UIDateTimeAttribute : UIHintAttribute
{
  public UIDateTimeAttribute(bool canShowSeconds)
    : base("UIDateTime", "MVC")
  {
    CanShowSeconds = canShowSeconds;
  }

  public bool CanShowSeconds { get; private set; }
}
```

Then apply it to a model:

```
public class Person
{
  [UIDateTime(false)]
  public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

Then create your `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/UIDateTime.cshtml` file:

```
@model DateTime

@{
  var format = "dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss";

  // Get the container model (Person for example)
  var attribute = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType
    // Get the property we are displaying for (Birthday)
    .GetProperty(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)
    // Get all attributes of type UIDateTimeAttribute
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UIDateTimeAttribute))
    // Cast the result as UIDateTimeAttribute
    .Select(a => a as UIDateTimeAttribute)
    // Get the first one or null
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a != null);

  if (attribute != null && !attribute.CanShowSeconds)
  {
    format = "dd-MM-yy hh:mm";
  }
}

@Model.ToString(format)
```

Comment: I thought about this way too, and unfortunately it seems not possible to change the path to the view, which would be good to share the editor between different projects.

Comment: You want to give the attribute to much [responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Paths are a property of a directory, which the [RazorViewEngine](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/RazorViewEngine.cs) use to locate views. UIHint is simply a way to annotate that this property should use some other view (without path).

Comment: The problem is that the attribute is defined in another assembly to reuse the editor in multiplice apps. To do this with the views, I use [RazorGenerator](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator). But there I need to specify the full path. Your example isn't working with that, I tried it with multiplice variants of the path in the constructor. But outside with the full path like `@Html.Partial("/Views/Editor.cshtml")` its working, so this problem seems related to UIHint. Thats the reason I want to have a full custom attribute.

Comment: Without the code that *isn't working*, I can't help.

Comment: I used this answer to create autocomplete UIHint attribute http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.com/2016/08/autocomplete-using-customized-uihint.html